# Почему Sum считается неверно?

Tags: python, django

`qs` - QuerySet из нескольких объектов. Мне нужно выполнить для него ряд фильтраций.

```py
if min_qty:
    qs = qs.filter(stocks__count__gte=min_qty)

qs = qs.annotate(all_qty=Sum('stocks__count'))

print(sum([stock.count for stock in qs.first().stocks.all()]))
print(qs.first().all_qty)
```

Я ожидаю, что результат первого и второго принта здесь будет всегда одинаковый, т.к. и в первом и во-втором случая я хочу вывести сумму наличия на всех складах. И если не выполяется условие в блоке if - это действительно так. Но как только появляется `min_qty` и выполняется условие в блоке if, принты выдают разные цифры. Я не понимаю как это происходит и как этот иф вообще может влиять на то, что происходит дальше. Что я делаю не так?

Значение меняется именно при расчете `Sum`. Первый принт выдает всегда одно и то же.

Comment: наверное не так понял вопрос.

Выведи sql запрос в обоих вариантах - может станет яснее

Comment: @eri а как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте название переменных изменить...

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 каких именно? qs?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 или count?

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 переименование count во всем проекте не помогло :(

Comment: @eri в одном из случаев 2 раза приджойниваются склады и это вызывает ошибку. Но я тогде не понимаю почему так и что с этим делать

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это из-за annotate - у тебя в qs есть групировка и в sum([]) в цикле, ты считаешь все элементы, а когда выводишь all_qty, то берешь количество только первого элемента, поэтому и не совпадает. Посмотри сам sql запрос, он выводится через qs.query